# Grep only numbers, not the alphanumeric entries

Tags: grep, regular-expression, numeric-data

I have a list of values like:

```
1
2
3
4
Ak123
Ak23
Ak147
1Apple
2Apricot
3Mango
4Orange
```

I just want to execute a simple grep command to list me only the numbers. i.e. `1`, `2` , `3` and `4`.
I tried this command -

```
grep -Ein --color '^\s*[0-9]' test.txt
```

but it returns the alphanumeric also. Instead I tried omitting the character by this command:

```
grep -Ein --color '^\s*[0-9][^A-Z]' test.txt
```

but it gives 0 results.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming each line only contains a single word with no flanking whitespace:

```
grep -x -E '[0-9]+'
```

or

```
grep -x -E '[[:digit:]]+'
```

This would extract any line that contained only digits.  The `-x` option to `grep` forces the pattern to match across a complete line.  I'm using `-E` to enable extended regular expression to be able to use `+`.

The pattern `[[:digit:]]+` would match at least one digit.  The type of digit that it matches may depend on your locale.

To allow for whitespace before and after:

```
grep -x -E '[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+[[:blank:]]*'
```

or

```
grep -x -E '[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*'
```

The pattern `[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more tabs or spaces.

---

Your expression `^\s*[0-9]` matches lines that may start with a space character (assuming `\s` matches a space character, it's really a PCRE) and then has a digit.  After the digit, any character may occur, as in the string `2Apricot`.

Your expression `^\s*[0-9][^A-Z]` is similar, but `[^A-Z]` forces the matching of a second non-alphabetic non-uppercase character.  This matches things like `33`, `1a`, and `5-` and longer strings, but would not match the single character string `3`.

Comment: Awesome... Thank you so much. All of them worked. I just can't understand what the -X option really does?

Comment: @SrinivasanSenthil You mean `-x` (lowercase).  As I wrote, it forces the match to span the whole line. It's like including `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern. It makes it easier to read the expressions when you're matching a whole line.

Answer (score 4):

Try also

```
$ grep -v '[^ 0-9]' file
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I like this approach. Instead of "show me what I want", it's "discard what I don't want" -- It just depends what's easier to quantify, "what I want" or "what I don't want".

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}' filename
```

`-Eo` only outputs that data that is numeric, matches that one in the `[]` while numbers in `{}` show the length of numbers you want to grep.

Comment: Yes, that is extracting the numbers on all lines. But the OP asked that lines with alphanumeric were not matched. Try without the `o` to see all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | grep -v '[[:alpha:]]' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to change the last `grep` to `grep -Eo '[0-9]+'` so that it doesn't match empty lines.